# Lint is warning me about API accesses not supported in all verions but it works everywhere?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lint

Lint is giving me this error a fair amount of times:

```
"match_parent" requires API level 8 (current min is 4), use "fill_parent" instead
```

I understand the error. I'm using `match_parent` in all of the XML layouts my app uses and never use `fill_parent` cause it's deprecated. However, as you can understand from the error above, my `minSdkVersion` is 4 and `match_parent` is only available on 8.

The thing is, I ran my app on a Cupcake emulator and the app works just fine. Why? Shouldn't it crash or something?

What's the right way to work around this issue, ignore this specific Lint error for all the XML files or just put back `fill_parent` everywhere?

Comment: definitely use `fill_parent` if you mean to support since API v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because they have the same numerical value, and the value is what winds up in the APK file, not the symbol.

> What's the right way to work around this issue, ignore this specific Lint error for all the XML files or just put back fill_parent everywhere?

For lint warnings where you know you are using the stuff correctly, you can [add annotations in Java (and similar markers in XML)](http://tools.android.com/recent/ignoringlintwarnings) indicating that you know what you are doing, and lint will no longer complain.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that, they are just numerical values. Yes, I know about the annotations. But those will make the XML really large and confusing, I use them everywhere. I renamed all of them to `match_parent` because I was having some "deprecation" warnings in the XML. I put some of the attributes back to `fill_parent` and I don't seem to get those warnings now. Maybe something changed in ADT and how they handle this...

Comment: @RicardoAmaral: Oh, in this particular case, there's nothing wrong with using `fill_parent`. The core Android team thought `match_parent` was a more accurate description... which I still do not understand. I was trying to be a bit more general-purpose in my answer, and I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: I though so, but I like i said, I changed them all from `fill_parent` to `match_parent` because of deprecation warnings. Which I don't see anymore and Lint is warning me about using `match_parent` so I might as well revert them all back. Thanks.